# Debian/PostFix/Gmail not playing well

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, gmail

I followed [these instructions](http://www.marksanborn.net/linux/send-mail-postfix-through-gmails-smtp-on-a-ubuntu-lts-server/) and took hints from other sites. I cant get my server to send emails using google apps (i spent 3 hours on this already.)

I get the error

```
Authentication Required.
    Learn more at                               530 5.5.1
    http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257
```

My postfix files are

http://www.privatepaste.com/a287ea4967

I verified my user/pass is correct. I tested with the command `sendmail -bv addr@domain.com` and use mail to see the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `transport_maps` directive from your `main.cf` and change the value of `relayhost` to `[smtp.gmail.com]:587`. Don't forget to run `postmap` on the hash files (`sasl_passwd`) after a change.

Also make sure to read http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl and actually understand it.

Postfix is quite overkill if you just want to send mails from your server through the `sendmail` interface. In this case you should use a minimal MTA like `ssmtp` or `nbsmtp` instead.

Comment: Switching to ssmtp solved it. It was damn easy. I dont know why postfix didnt work nor why doing what you suggested above for postfix didnt work. I'm happy it finally works. Thanks!